# C# Azure Blob Storage upload on slow internet connection fail

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using the Azure Blob storage client library v12 for .NET i used this guide to setup https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet

It is all working fine on internet connections with fast upload speeds but once I try run this program on a site with upload speed on 1Mbps it doesnt work i have now been able to replicate this issue but using software on my computer to restrict the upload speed in my dev environment when i set the upload speed to 1Mbps it fails to upload the file after about 10 minutes of trying

The file is about 15Mb of json

15Mb file should upload in about 2 - 3 minutes on 1Mbps i would think

This is the code i am trying to use as i said when tested on 30Mbps upload connection it all working fine

```
public static async Task UploadData(string json)
 {


BlobClientOptions MyBlobClientOptions = new BlobClientOptions
            {
                Transport = new HttpClientTransport(
                    new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600) })
            };

 //Setup Azure BlobServiceClient
            string datetime = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            string AzureConnectionString = _iconfiguration.GetConnectionString("AzureStorage");
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(AzureConnectionString,MyBlobClientOptions);

            string localFilePath = $"{TempDirPath}data{datetime}.json";

            // Write text to the file
            await File.WriteAllTextAsync(localFilePath, json);
            string localFileName = $"UPLOAD_SPEED_TEST/data{datetime}.json";


            // Get a reference to a blob
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("data");
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(localFileName);

            _logger.LogInformation("Uploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t {0}\n", blobClient.Uri);

     try
        {

            //Test this Option to see if it would fix upload issue on slow connections
            StorageTransferOptions transferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions();
            transferOptions.MaximumConcurrency = 2;

            // Open the file and upload its data
            using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);
            uploadFileStream.Position = 0;
            
            // Upload file to Azure Blob Storage
            blobClient.Upload(uploadFileStream, transferOptions: transferOptions);
            _logger.LogInformation("UPLOAD COMPLETE");
            uploadFileStream.Close();

        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Error upload Failed
            _logger.LogInformation("UPLOAD ERROR" + ex.ToString());
        }
}
```

Error Message

```
System.AggregateException: Retry failed after 6 tries. (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.)
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<WriteSingleChunk>g__CompleteAsync|210_1[TWriteAdapter](ValueTask writeTask, Byte[] bufferToReturn)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncChunked[TWriteAdapter](TWriteAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncInternal[TWriteAdapter](TWriteAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 source)
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.RequestContent.StreamContent.WriteToAsync(Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellation)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.PipelineRequest.PipelineContentAdapter.SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore(ValueTask copyTask)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore(ValueTask copyTask)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendRequestContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpContentWriteStream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.Process(HttpMessage message)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineTransportPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.ProcessNextAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean isAsync)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean isAsync)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipeline.Send(HttpMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.BlockBlob.UploadAsync(ClientDiagnostics clientDiagnostics, HttpPipeline pipeline, Uri resourceUri, Stream body, Int64 contentLength, String version, Nullable`1 timeout, Byte[] transactionalContentHash, String blobContentType, String blobContentEncoding, String blobContentLanguage, Byte[] blobContentHash, String blobCacheControl, IDictionary`2 metadata, String leaseId, String blobContentDisposition, String encryptionKey, String encryptionKeySha256, Nullable`1 encryptionAlgorithm, String encryptionScope, Nullable`1 tier, Nullable`1 ifModifiedSince, Nullable`1 ifUnmodifiedSince, Nullable`1 ifMatch, Nullable`1 ifNoneMatch, String requestId, Boolean async, String operationName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlockBlobClient.UploadInternal(Stream content, BlobHttpHeaders blobHttpHeaders, IDictionary`2 metadata, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Nullable`1 accessTier, IProgress`1 progressHandler, String operationName, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted[T](Task`1 task)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.PartitionedUploader.Upload(Stream content, BlobHttpHeaders blobHttpHeaders, IDictionary`2 metadata, BlobRequestConditions conditions, IProgress`1 progressHandler, Nullable`1 accessTier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.StagedUploadAsync(Stream content, BlobHttpHeaders blobHttpHeaders, IDictionary`2 metadata, BlobRequestConditions conditions, IProgress`1 progressHandler, Nullable`1 accessTier, StorageTransferOptions transferOptions, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted[T](Task`1 task)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.Upload(Stream content, BlobHttpHeaders httpHeaders, IDictionary`2 metadata, BlobRequestConditions conditions, IProgress`1 progressHandler, Nullable`1 accessTier, StorageTransferOptions transferOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at LMGAgent.AzureStorage.UploadBasketData(String json) in C:\Users\anewman\source\repos\agent\LMGAgent\AzureStorage.cs:line 68
 ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<WriteSingleChunk>g__CompleteAsync|210_1[TWriteAdapter](ValueTask writeTask, Byte[] bufferToReturn)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncChunked[TWriteAdapter](TWriteAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncInternal[TWriteAdapter](TWriteAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 source)
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.RequestContent.StreamContent.WriteToAsync(Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellation)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.PipelineRequest.PipelineContentAdapter.SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore(ValueTask copyTask)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore(ValueTask copyTask)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendRequestContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpContentWriteStream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.Process(HttpMessage message)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineTransportPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.ProcessNextAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean isAsync)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean isAsync)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)<---

 ---> (Inner Exception #2) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<WriteSingleChunk>g__CompleteAsync|210_1[TWriteAdapter](ValueTask writeTask, Byte[] bufferToReturn)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncChunked[TWriteAdapter](TWriteAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncInternal[TWriteAdapter](TWriteAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 source)
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.RequestContent.StreamContent.WriteToAsync(Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellation)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.PipelineRequest.PipelineContentAdapter.SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore(ValueTask copyTask)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore(ValueTask copyTask)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendRequestContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpContentWriteStream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.Process(HttpMessage message)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineTransportPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.ProcessNextAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean isAsync)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean isAsync)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)<---

 ---> (Inner Exception #3) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<WriteSingleChunk>g__CompleteAsync|210_1[TWriteAdapter](ValueTask writeTask, Byte[] bufferToReturn)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncChunked[TWriteAdapter](TWriteAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncInternal[TWriteAdapter](TWriteAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 source)
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.RequestContent.StreamContent.WriteToAsync(Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellation)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.PipelineRequest.PipelineContentAdapter.SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore(ValueTask copyTask)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore(ValueTask copyTask)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendRequestContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpContentWriteStream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Please share the code so we can better help.

Comment: I have added all the code from the upload method.

Comment: Please try the solution outlined in this Github thread: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/9212.

Comment: I have updated my code and tried BlobClientOptions as @GauravMantri-AIS but i still have the same error

Comment: Oh! Other option would be to manually split the blob into blocks and do chunked uploads. That would give you more control over the upload as you can set the block size as per your need (I believe the default is 256MB).

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS do you have a reference as to how i could do this with the V12 SDK ?

Comment: Please see some code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678140/azure-block-blob-the-specified-block-list-is-invalid-when-committing-previous. Basically you will split the file in blocks, read those blocks and upload them using `StageBlock` method. Once all blocks are uploaded, you call `CommitBlockList` method to commit those blocks and create the blob. If you still need help, please let me know. I will try to create a sample.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this same issue exception when trying to upload a 60MB file over a 4Mbps connection.:

> System.AggregateException: Retry failed after 6 tries.

I did the following to get it working for me:

1. Set the `Retry` timeout as well as the `Transport` timeout (thanks to [this GitHub post](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/9212#issuecomment-678548888) for that idea):

```cs
var blobClientOptions = new BlobClientOptions
{
    Transport = new HttpClientTransport(new HttpClient { Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan }),
    Retry = { NetworkTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan }
};
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60533398/1879019) for more on setting the Retry options.

2. I also overwrote the cancellation token in the hope of stopping the code calling my function cancelling it:

```cs
await blobClient.UploadAsync(
    content: uploadFileStream, httpHeaders: 
    cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);
```

Comment: nice one,  just what I needed in my scenario

Answer (score 0):

As Gaurav said, you need to split the file in blocks and read those blocks and upload them using `StageBlock` method. Once all blocks are uploaded, you call `CommitBlockList` method to commit those blocks and create the blob.

Please refer to this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678140/azure-block-blob-the-specified-block-list-is-invalid-when-committing-previous).